# pyspark groupby sum all in one time vs partial where then groupby sum for huge table

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

suppose we have very very huge table similar like this.
if we use pyspark to call this table and  `groupby("id").agg('value':'sum')`

comparing with
partial call this table by
 `where date first`  then
 `groupby("id").agg('value':'sum')`

then sum all partial values together.

Which one should be faster?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try executing and find out?

Comment: sure, I have done it. The operation took long time. So I just want to know the direction.
In summary , for my case, the partial read and group by was faster and consume smaller read size

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate your question ? I am assuming that you want to perform the following operations

case-1: sum(value) group by id (adds all date)

case-2: sum(value) group by id where date = 1

In either case, your performance will depend on the following:

1. Cardinality of your id column. Whether you have a very large number of unique values or small unique values repeating.
2. The type of file format you are using. If it is columnar (like parquet) vs row (like csv)
3. The partitioning and bucketing strategy you are using for storing the files. If date columns hold few values, go for partitioning, else bucketing.

All these factors will help determine whether the above 2 cases will show similar processing time or they will drastically be different. This is due to the fact, that reading large amount of data will take more time than reading less / pruned data with given filters. Also, your shuffle block size and partitions play key role